# tableView calling another tableView, indexPath with parameters

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, xcode4, xcode4.5

The first tableview has to pass parameter to second tableView, I will use to create a select whith SQLite to create the second tableView, created after the second tableview will call a viewcontroller.

I searched but not found here.

help me. tanks.

I'm sorry for my english is not well understandable.

Comment: What is your problem?your question is not clear...

Comment: I tried to use **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** to get the indexPath value and move to the second TableView to use the title and for a select Sqlite.

Comment: @FabricioAguiar So what's not working then?  The SQL statement, the pushing of the new view controller, or the index path?

Comment: so you need index path value of particular row?

Comment: I'm sorry I have not explained very well.
I'll try to explain better.
I have the first TableView populated by brands.
example

Porche, Ferrari and Maserati.

second TableView all models.

Example.
When selecting Porche, the second TableView is popular with:
911,
Carrera GT,
Cayenny S

my query with First TableView.

`Select name from brands`

my query with second TableView.

`Select name from brand where model = **ferrari**`

I just need to pass the object from the first TableView Porsche or Ferrari or Maserati, so I put in the second query TableView.

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry that i can not able to write all code here,But this [answer](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/54859-sharing-data-between-view-controllers-and-other-objects-link-fixed.html) is help you to share data between viewcontroller.

Add this code in ExampleAppDataObject.h

```
NSString*   carName;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* carName;
```

and in .m file

```
@synthesize carName;


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark -Memory management methods

- (void)dealloc 
{
    //Release any properties declared as retain or copy.
    self.carName = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

and add carName in your first tableview when row selected.

Answer (score 0):

Use Segue to pass the data of the row selection on the first view controller to the 2nd.